Session not maintained across end points in flask - react project
I'm currently working on a project that uses Flask as the backend and React as the front end, the issue that I face is that I'm not able to pass the values in session to other endpoints, ie the session is removed on the call of every other endpoint,  the flask app uses cors.
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    

    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.json.get('email')
        password = request.json.get('password')
        try:
            
            user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
            session['user'] = user
            print(user)
            print("&&&&&")
            print(session["user"]["localId"])
            
            info  = session["user"]
            
            return jsonify({'success': True, 'message': 'Login successful'})
        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify({'success': False, 'error': str(e)}), 200  
    return jsonify({'success': False, 'error': 'Method not allowed'}), 405  # Method Not Allowed status code

@app.route('/transfer_style', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def transfer_style():
    if 'user' in session:
        return jsonify({'success': False, 'error': 'Invalid data'}), 400
      


    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("jofdojfdjjdovjdovjodjvdjnvjjjjjjjjjjjjjj")
        """current_session = session._get_current_object() 
        print(session["user"]["localId"])
        user_id = current_session.get('user')
        print(user_id)"""

        user_id = session['localId'] #session does not get passed to here
        print(user_id)   #no data avilable

        print(info)
        

        content_file = request.files['content']
        style_file = request.files['style']
        epochs = int(request.form.get('epochs', 1))
        steps_per_epoch = int(request.form.get('steps_per_epoch', 5))

 code contiue...

from flask import Flask, jsonify, request,  redirect, url_for, session,send_file
import pyrebase
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
#from flask import request

#
# from firebase_admin import auth


app = Flask(__name__)

CORS(app,supports_credentials=True)

app.secret_key = os.urandom(24).hex()

please help
I have tried to copy the value to a global variable - does not work
tried CORS(app,supports_credentials=True) - does not work
